# What is the best way to do SO style routes (dashes as spaces)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Just wondering what the best way to do SO style routes is.

[What is the best way to do SO style routes (dashes as spaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459559/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-so-style-routes-dashes-as-spaces)

What's the best way to create routes like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [ASP.NET MVC and Clean SEO Friendly URLs](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls?replyId=122&replyWithQuote=True) on Dominic Pettifer's blog.

> It works on a white-list principle, allowing all 0-9 and a-z characters through, dealing with a few special cases, and converting everything else to -hyphens-. You'll notice that spaces are being converted to hyphens as well, and you might be tempted to use *underscores* instead. Don't! There are sound SEO benefits for using hyphens in that search engines bots treat them as spaces.

Comment: Apparently the link is dead.

Comment: @Disco Thanks for letting me know. When I'm not on mobile I'll see if I can sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's one way](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/10/function-to-generate-a-url-friendly-string.aspx).

[Here's another](http://www.softcircuits.com/Blog/post/2010/05/12/Converting-Text-to-a-URL-Slug.aspx).

It's called a [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)) btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to replace any non-alphanumeric character with a dash. You could search for this regex `[^\w]+` and replace with `-`.

Comment: Does this convert multiple spaces into one hyphen?

Comment: No, this is a regular expression to find the characters that *will* be replaced by hyphen. Actual code might look like: `strInput = Regex.Replace(strInput,"[^\w]+","-")`

Comment: Yeah...I just meant will that regex treat multiple spaces as one. Regexes are like chinese to me :)

Comment: Regexes are good to learn. Eventually you will come across problems where a regex solution will be much easier than the non-regex solution. If you want a good place to learn, start with http://www.regular-expressions.info/